# Webpack 4: Cannot resolve dependancy of symlinked module

Tags: webpack, symlink, webpack-4, lerna

After upgrading from Webpack 1 to 4, I've encountered the following error:

```js
ERROR in ./node_modules/@my_symlinked_packages/base-accessibility-date-picker/lib/components/AcessibleDatePicker.component.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dates/lib/utils/isInclusivelyAfterDay' in '/path_to_my_local_app/node_modules/@my_symlinked_packages/base-accessibility-date-picker/lib/components'
 @ ./node_modules/@my_symlinked_packages/base-accessibility-date-picker/lib/components/AcessibleDatePicker.component.js 32:29-83
 @ ./node_modules/@my_symlinked_packages/base-accessibility-date-picker/lib/index.js
 @ ./app/components/borrowing/holds/HoldsPauseDateSelect/HoldsPauseDateSelect.jsx
 @ ./app/components/borrowing/holds/HoldsPauseDateSelect/index.js
 @ ./app/components/borrowing/holds/PauseHoldWorkflowView/components/BasePauseHoldWorkflowView.jsx
 @ ./app/components/borrowing/holds/PauseHoldWorkflowView/components/SinglePauseHoldWorkflowView.jsx
 @ ./app/containers/ItemTransactionWorkflowContainer.jsx
 @ ./app/containers/WorkflowContainer.jsx
 @ ./app/components/widgets/ItemWidget/ItemWidget.jsx
 @ ./app/components/widgets/ItemWidget/index.js
 @ ./app/containers/widgets/ItemWidgetContainer.jsx
 @ ./app/routes/Routes.jsx
 @ ./app/bootstrap.js
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3002 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./app/bootstrap.js
```

I believe this error is indicating that Wepback 4 cannot resolve react-dates module which is a dependancy of a module that I am symlinking.

Here's a sample of my project layout:

```js
my_symlinked_packages
|-node_modules
|-package.json
|-src
  |-my_lerna_package1
    |-lib
    |-specs
    |-src
    |-package.json (contains react-dates as a dependancy)


consuming_application
|-node_modules
  |-@my_symlinked_packages
    |-my_lerna_package1
|-package.json
|-webpack.config.js
|-app
```

Here's an example of my webpack.config.js (it's being composed of several js imports)

```js
  //import dependancies
  //assign value to custom variables

  module.exports = { 
    devtool: 'eval',
    context: '/path_to_my_local_app',
    mode: 'development',
    entry:
    { app:
        [ 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3002',
          'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
          './app/bootstrap.js' ],
      vendors:
        [ 'raf/polyfill',
          'babel-polyfill',
          'immutable',
          'iso',
          'jquery',
          'lodash',
          'moment',
          'react',
          'react-router',
          'redux',
          'react-redux',
          'superagent',
          'when',
          'rxjs',
          'handlebars' ] },
    externals: [ 'farmhash' ],
    output:
    { path: '/path_to_my_local_app/public',
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3002/' },
    module:
    { rules:
        [ {
          use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'happypack/loader?id=babel'],
          test:    /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          include: /app|server|node_modules\/@my_symlinked_packages/
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          include: /app|server/
        },
        {
          test:   /\.s?css$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
              loader:'css-loader',
              options: {
                importLoaders: 2,
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            { 
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: postcssConfig } }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }]
        },
        {
          test:   /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=' + inlinedAssetSizeLimit
        },
        {
          test: require.resolve('jquery'),
          loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery'
        },
        {
          test: /handlebars\.js/,
          loader: 'expose-loader?Handlebars'
        } ] },
    resolve:
    { symlinks: false,
      modules:
        [ '/path_to_my_local_app/app',
          '/path_to_my_local_app/node_modules',
          '/path_to_my_local_app/vendor' ],
      alias:
        { handlebars: 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
          containers: '/path_to_my_local_app/app/containers',
          constants: '/path_to_my_local_app/app/constants',
          actions: '/path_to_my_local_app/app/actions' },
      extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx' ] },
    plugins: [ // hot reload
      new HappyPack({
        id: 'babel',
        threads: 4,
        loaders: [
          {
            loader:  'babel-loader',
            query: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __CLIENT__: true,
        __SERVER__: false,
        __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
        __DISABLE_SSR__: false
      }),
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
          sassLoader: {
            data: `$is-widget: ${widgetBuild ? 'true' : 'false'};`
          },
          eslint: {
            emitWarning: true
          },
          progress: true
        }
      }),

      // https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools
      new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(webpackIsomorphicToolsConfig).development()
    ]
  }
```

And here is a snippet of my postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {
      browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie >= 9', 'iOS >= 8']
    }
  }
};
```

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: My current work around to this issue is to install the missing dependancy in the consuming application but this is not an optimal solution as I'm expecting all dependancies from my symlinked lerna mono repos to be resolved correctly.

Comment: Here's an demo repo which replicates the error being discussed if anyone would like to take a look: https://bitbucket.org/omar-biblio/webpack-symlink-error-demo/src/master/

Answer (score 2):

We were able to solve this issue by adding a resolve path pointing to the nodule modules of the symlinked directory.

```
// example shows resolve config pointing to the directory which stores the
// symlinked mono repos
    module.exports = {
      resolve : {
        modules: [
          path.resolve('./app'),
          path.resolve('./node_modules'),
          path.resolve('./vendor'),
          path.resolve('../my_symlinked_packages/node_modules')
        ]
      }
    };
```

Comment: I'm curious if you ever came across a better way of handling this? Also, thanks for answering your own question for the benefit of others!